# Why ChronoUnit.HOURS.between() is NOT working?

Tags: java, java-time, date-difference, chronounit

I was trying to get the hours between two local dates. And I used the code below :

```
 LocalDate startDate =  LocalDate.of(2000, 4, 30);

    long noOfHours = startDate.until(LocalTime.now(), ChronoUnit.HOURS);
    
    System.out.println(noOfHours);
```

I am having the error below :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: 13:44:53.095819600 of type java.time.LocalTime
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.from(LocalDate.java:397)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.until(LocalDate.java:1645)
    at BirthDay.App.main(App.java:36)
```

Comment: `LocalTime` does not have a Date component, it is only a time, e.g. "13:37:01" but _not_ "2021-07-10T13:37:01". And `LocalDate#until` simply does not support `HOURS` (have a look at the implementation). Why? Because `LocalDate` does not have a time component, only a date ("2000-04-30", but not "2000-04-30T00:00:00")

Comment: From [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#until(java.time.temporal.Temporal,java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)): ***Throws:** `DateTimeException` - if the amount cannot be calculated, or the end temporal cannot be converted to a `LocalDate`*. The latter is the case here: there is no way to convert a `LocalTime` to a `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Error 1

As the exception states : you need coherent bound values, `LocalTime` has no day/month/year composants to be compared to a `LocalDate`

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2000, 4, 30);
long noOfHours = startDate.until(LocalTime.now(), ChronoUnit.HOURS);
// >> DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDate from java.time.LocalTime
```

---

#### Error 2

Also you need composants that have the unit required by your `ChronoUnit`, using 2 `LocalDate` won't work with `HOURS` as they have none.

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2000, 4, 30);
long noOfHours = startDate.until(LocalDate.now(), ChronoUnit.HOURS);
// >> UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported unit: Hours
```

---

Use `LocalDateTime` for that, to be coherent for both bounds **and** for unit time

```
LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDateTime.of(2000, 4, 30, 0, 0, 0);
long noOfHours = startDate.until(LocalDateTime.now(), ChronoUnit.HOURS);
System.out.println(noOfHours); // 185793
```

Answer (score 5):

Note that `LocalDate` has not time component, and `LocalTime` has no date component. So your code is trying to calculate the number of hours between 2000-04-30 (with no time specified), and the current local time (with no date specified). See the problem?

What you probably meant is,

> How many hours are there, between *today* at the current local time, and 2000-04-30 *at the start of that day* (or some other time that day)?

This calculation needs two "date+time"s, not one date and one time. We represent that with `LocalDateTime`.

```
long noOfHours = startDate.atStartOfDay().until(LocalDateTime.now(), ChronoUnit.HOURS);
```

Note `LocalDateTime.now()` and `atStartOfDay`, which returns `LocalDateTime`s.

If you want to use another time at 2000-04-30, use `startDate.atTime(...)`, or create a `LocalDateTime` in the first place, e.g.

```
LocalDateTime startDate =  LocalDateTime.of(2000, 4, 30, 12, 30);
```

Comment: @AhmedAjmineNehal If you think an answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!